# How to auto-import AVCHD video?

Tags: video, import, image-capture

I need a way to just auto-copy AVCHD from my memory card to the Mac.

The Image Capture and AutoImporter apps both work great for still photos and for MP4 video. Image Capture completely ignores AVCHD, while AutoImporter seems to hang when I plug in the memory card with some AVCHD clips:

[image]

When manually browsing the memory card, there is on its root level a package called "PRIVATE":

[image]

And only 3 levels down can I find the actual MTS files that should be copied... :

[image]

How can I get these videos to be auto-copied when I plug in the memory card?

Answer (score 1):

Try the free [AVCHD to MOV Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-avchd-to-mov/id675103877?mt=12) on the App Store to convert it to MOV format, and then import to Photos. This will `remux` the video (convert it without reprocessing/converting the audio or video) losslessly.

(Hat tip to [How can I convert .MTS file (AVCHD) to .mp4 by ffmpeg without re-encoding H264 video stream?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/how-can-i-convert-mts-file-avchd-to-mp4-by-ffmpeg-without-re-encoding-h264-v?newreg=6b144c4e8b8f4b55a4725a969f5e3167)
).